# What is creating ./var/lib in my yocto image?

Tags: yocto

**tl;dr** Yocto creates an empty directory `var/lib` in my image, even after it has been explicitly deleted by `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND`. Why, and how can I get rid of it?

---

I am trying to create an yocto image with an exact predefined set of files and directories, without the usual rootfs files. To start with, I'm trying to create a completely empty image.

For testing purposes I'm using a clean yocto jethro clone with `MACHINE ??= "qemux86"` in `conf/local.conf`. Let's start with this recipe

```
meta-selftest/recipes-test/images/test-empty-image.bb
```

which comes with the yocto clone. It is very simple:

```
SUMMARY = "An empty image."
IMAGE_INSTALL = ""
IMAGE_LINGUAS = ""
PACKAGE_INSTALL = ""

inherit image
```

Building `bitbake test-empty-image` gives me the following files in the image:

```
$ tar tf tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/test-empty-image-qemux86.tar.bz2 
./
./etc/
./etc/version
./etc/default/
./etc/default/postinst
./etc/ld.so.cache
./etc/rpm/
./etc/rpm/platform
./etc/rpm/sysinfo/
./etc/rpm/sysinfo/Dirnames
./etc/timestamp
./var/
./var/lib/
```

Let's try to delete the remaining files and folders by appending this to the recipe:

```
remove_dirs () {
        rm -rf ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc
        rm -rf ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/var 
}
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "remove_dirs ; "
```

This works for `etc`, but not for `var`:

```
$ tar tf tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/test-empty-image-qemux86.tar.bz2
./
./var/
./var/lib/
```

For some more debugging, I add logging statements to the cleanup function:

```
remove_dirs () {
        echo "################# Listing before rm -rf:" >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/listing.txt
        ls ${IMAGE_ROOTFS} >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/listing.txt
        rm -rf ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc
        rm -rf ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/var 
        echo "################# Listing after rm -rf:" >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/listing.txt
        ls ${IMAGE_ROOTFS} >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/listing.txt
}
```

which results in the file `listing.txt`:

```
################# Listing before rm -rf:
etc
listing.txt
oe_install
var
################# Listing after rm -rf:
listing.txt
oe_install
```

So the directory `var/lib` is definitely deleted by the `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND`, but than apparently recreated later. How can I get rid of this directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite annoying and in the past I had the same problem. Do the following in your image recipe:

IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND += "remove_dirs"

This should run after the ROOTFS part.

See [Yocto manual entry for IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-IMAGE_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND)